# What do I need to do for the quest "The Lost Treasure"?

Tags: borderlands-2

The quest "The Lost Treasure" has brought me to the Caustic Caverns. I now shall follow four clues, but the quest description is awfully vague. Can anyone point out where and what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are switches near the areas alluded to. They're the standard switches that glow green, then turn red when switched.

Once you press all four there's an elevator you'll ride up to the location of the treasure. They can be pressed in any order and once they're pressed the corresponding mission item is marked Completed. The objectives are ordered by how early on in the level they are (starting by going to the right from the entrance) and the clues are fairly obvious once you know you're looking for switches.

Answer (score 1):

The lost treasure asks you to find 4 switches if you already obtained the map pieces. There are 4 clues for you to find the hidden switches.

1. under the bridge : you can find this one under the broken bridge(Crystalisk Area) its easy you need to go to 3rd or 4th pillar and try searching there. If i remember correctly its on the pillar.
2. In Warehouse on the shore : if you been to caustic caverns before then i think you remember the warehouse full of varkids. Search for the switch on where warehouse meets shoreline(Follow the exit wall to right i.e. North East corner of warehouse).
3. In shadow of digger : No go ahead you will be in an area where crystalisk spwans. and you will see some mine carts and tracks. look for a big digger in the sky (its have big round saw-blade like thing). Just look in the shadow of the digger and you will find your 3rd switch there.
4. In hyperions 6th : this will be inside hyperion's building. if i remember correctly then in the room with lots of lockers.

Once all 4 switches are pressed the elevator(Slasher Area) will power on, go ride up the elevators and fight varkids/spiderants (badass included). And you will get the gun 
So good luck

PS: I wrote the clues description based on my memory could be a bit wrong.

Comment: Note that once you hit the four switches, an elevator near-ish the 3rd switch becomes active which you need to go up